# Symfony API Two Step Authentication

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

I am developing a Symfony API application with two-step authentication. First step is `json_login` form with username and password and second step is OTP with SMS service.
After json_login succeeded, json_login authenticator has to create JWT. Because, I use tokens instead of PHP sessions. It's configured in security.yaml file by `stateless: true` option.

```
# security.yaml
stateless: true
json_login:
check_path: app_login
     username_path: email
     password_path: password
```

It is possible making many different authenticators and firewalls with Symfony Framework.
In the first step (json_login), the user is authenticated and is authorized to access the whole system. However, the user must have access to the entire system after the OTP step. Which method can I use for two-factor authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tips that have helped me in the past :

- Google Authenticator : https://github.com/sonata-project/GoogleAuthenticator (Which is implementation of original code provided by google but dedicated for PHP)
- 2fa : https://github.com/scheb/2fa,

  - Note that https://github.com/scheb/two-factor-bundle is outdated, instead, it is recomended to use https://github.com/scheb/2fa for recent symfony version
  - 2fa is explain by the author here : https://www.christianscheb.de/archives/14
- SMS|Email verification, you can use Authy bundle for Symfony used with twilio, but the recommended way is to use Verify API (https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api)

---

After the implementation of these bricks, you need to add the business logic of your API

Comment: I have to configurate 2fa bundle for JWT. I can't use external user systems like Twillio for security reasons. I will share results of my working. Thanks @Mahefa

Comment: Thanks @karatas.hakan